# What do the numbers in "%0" or "%1" mean in C/C++ GCC Inline Assembly

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly

I'm Reading the gcc documentation about the inline assembly,there was an operand syntax like %0,%1,%2 what this number mean ?, in their documentation this is not explained.

Comment: A question title should actually ask your question, not just say what tools the question is about; edited towards that end, please try to do so yourself in the future.

Comment: It is actually buried in the manual; searching on the word "number" will find *Therefore it references the first output operand as %0 (were there a second, it would be %1, etc*  in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html